# how to change the media element source according to listbox item

Tags: c#, wpf

i am working with wpf media element.i want to change the media element source according to listbox item.

i created next button when clicking the next buton ,listbox item changed to  next item.i dont know how to change the media element source to next listbox item when clicking the next button..

can any one have idea on this.

plz help me.thanks in advance....

my .xaml file...

```
<MediaElement Margin="7,29,80,6" Name="mediaElement1" LoadedBehavior="Manual" 
    AllowDrop="True" MediaOpened="mediaElement1_MediaOpened" 

  Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="False" ScrubbingEnabled="True" IsEnabled="True"  
       Stretch="Fill" Drop="mediaElement1_Drop" ClipToBounds="False" 

 Visibility="Visible" OpacityMask="DarkRed" BufferingStarted="btn_play_click" 
  MediaEnded="mediaElement1_MediaEnded"  

  MouseLeftButtonUp="mediaElement1_MouseLeftButtonUp" Grid.Row="1" />


  <ListBox Margin="0,31,0,18" Name="listBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="74"  
  Grid.Row="1" MouseDoubleClick="listBox1_MouseDoubleClick" SelectedIndex="0" 
   SelectionMode="Multiple" AllowDrop="True"> </ListBox>
```

my next button code in .cs file is

```
private void btn_next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){   
  listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex + 1;
  mediaElement1.Source = new System.Uri(listBox1.SelectedValue as string);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx) instead of [SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue.aspx), or also set [SelectedValuePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath.aspx):

```
private void btn_next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex + 1; 
    mediaElement1.Source = new System.Uri(listBox1.SelectedItem as string); 
}
```

If you added ListBoxItems to the ListBox you would have to get their `Content`:

```
private void btn_next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex + 1;
    ListBoxItem item = listBox1.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
    mediaElement1.Source = new System.Uri(item.Content as string); 
}
```

Comment: i tried,and getting the following error."Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined."

Comment: Then, what items does your ListBox contain? Are they valid URIs? Maybe you show some code where you populate the ListBox.

Comment: this is .xaml code for list box                              <ListBox Margin="0,31,0,18" Name="listBox1" Grid.Row="1" MouseDoubleClick="listBox1_MouseDoubleClick" SelectedIndex="0" SelectionMode="Multiple" AllowDrop="True" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="61" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged" Visibility="Visible">

Comment: That is already in your question. What i mean is where you add items to the ListBox. Are you adding ListBoxItems? Then see my edited answer.

Comment: i tried ur edited code.error is getting,"Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: Then please **post the code** where you add items to the ListBox!

Comment: private void addplaylist_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd;
            ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.AddExtension = true;
            ofd.DefaultExt = "*.*";
            ofd.Filter = "media (*.*)|*.*";
            ofd.ShowDialog();
            listBox1.Items.Add(ofd.SafeFileName);
            
      
            

        }

Comment: Ok, it's a filename, so you can use `SelectedItem` directly. But see MSDN doc on [OpenFileDialog.SafeFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.safefilename.aspx). It is not an absolute path, so you can't make an URI from it directly. You have to convert it into an absolute path.

Comment: thanks for ur help.if it is a filename,its working..thanks.but how to convert safe filename into absolute path.u have any idea on that???.

Comment: Try the [FileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename.aspx) property, and perhaps read up on how to use FileDialog. And don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: thanks for ur help.and if u got any idea plz share here.thanks

Comment: Did you try [FileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename.aspx)? It should contain an absolute path.

Comment: but filename contains entire file path.it looking not good in playlist.