# Play song when listview item is selected

Tags: c#, windows-8

i want a user to select a song from a listview and play it. i tried: `listview.SelectedValuePath` i get a error: Url Is Blank. i tried: `listview.SelectedItem.ToString()` i get a error: Invalid Url.
The Listview items text is the file path. So it is not that.
My Full code:

```
FileOpenPicker picker = CreateFilePicker(audioExtensions);
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await picker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();

if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
{
    playlist = new Playlist();

    foreach (StorageFile file in files)
    {
        playlist.Files.Add(file);

        StorageFile savedFile =
            await playlist.SaveAsAsync(KnownFolders.MusicLibrary,
                                       "Sample",
                                       NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting,
                                       PlaylistFormat.WindowsMedia);

        this.OutputStatus.Text = savedFile.Name + " was created and saved with "
                                 + playlist.Files.Count + " files."
                                 + Environment.NewLine + "At folder: "
                                 + savedFile.Path;

        listview.Items.Add(file.Path.ToString());
    }
}
else
{
    this.OutputStatus.Text = "No files picked.";
}
```

My Listview changed:

```
   private void listview_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
                media.Source = new Uri(listview.SelectedValuePath);
   }
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for your listView SelectedItemChanged event?

Comment: @RobEpstein 
       private void listview_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
       {
                      media.Source = new Uri(listview.SelectedValuePath);

       }

Comment: @GrantWinney Alright updating now.

Comment: @AndrewGrinder MyListViewObject is that ListViewItem ?

Comment: @Christos92 No it's a custom class that you have to make. Create a class called FilePaths or something and give it 2 properties "Text" and "Value" or "Path" if you want. For each song, instantiate the class and provide content for the properties, then add that class to the list view items.

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476902/how-to-insert-object-type-in-listview

Comment: @AndrewGrinder Thanks that worked for me but i get a other error.Everytime a valid url is giving i get Invalid Source. I tried .mp3 and .mp4 files. even if i change the source manual.The 
zin met een hoofdletter en sluit af met een punt. The Sentences contains spaces maybe if this is the error

Comment: Try adding `@` in front of `file.Path.ToString()` ALSO can you show us the output of `listview.SelectedValuePath`?

Comment: Okay, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9800781/2367343

Comment: @AndrewGrinder your last comment with the link is exactly what i needed thank you ferry much :) post it as answer to i can mark you.

Comment: @AndrewGrinder The result of SelectedValuePath = The Url Is Empty...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58647/discussion-between-andrew-grinder-and-christos92).

Comment: @AndrewGrinder invite me ...

Answer (score 1):

First error `(Invalid Url Error)` fix is to add in ListViewItems into the ListView: [How to Insert Object Type in ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476902/how-to-insert-object-type-in-listview)

Second error `(Invalid Source)` fix is to get the `Content` from the Selected ListViewItem: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9800781/2367343

Comment: I got one more error -____- When i load a file i get Unsupported video type or invalid url. The url is valid because i my listview shows the exact same url as the music file. Local file:
C:\....

Comment: Try adding the `@` symbol to the beginning of any path strings. Like `media.Source = new Uri(@listview.SelectedValuePath);`